# How do I always have the same Web App URL when I do a new deployment?

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

Testing the new Google Apps Script editor, I noticed that when I make a change to the Script and re-deploy as a Web App, the URL in the deployed Web App changes. In the old editor this did not happen, the URL of the Web App was always the same.

This makes it very difficult, because every time I do a new Web App deployment I have to change the URL in the place where that Web App is called.

Will it always be like this in the new editor or is this a bug?

How do I always have the same Web App URL when I do a new deployment?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you click "Deploy" in the web app, make sure to then click "Manage deployments" and not "New deployment". In Manage deployments, make sure your deployment is highlighted on the left side. Click the pencil icon. From the version dropdown, select "New version". Click "Deploy". That should keep your existing web app URL.

Comment: Thanks. For better visualization I found this link https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43